# Employee Company Emulator

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```py
class HiringRequirements:
    def employee_eligible(self, employee, role):
        if employee.grades_percent_average >= self.minimum_hiring_grades_percent:
            if not self.role_occupied(role):
                return True
            else:
                print("Somebody is occupying this position.")
                return False
        else:
            print("You did not meet our requirements")
            return False


    def role_occupied(self, role):
        for (key, value) in self.employee_dict.items():
            for (attr, package) in value.items():
                if package == role:
                    return True
            else:
                return False

class Hirer:
    def employee_application(self, employee, role):
        apply = self.hire_employee(employee, role)
        hired = apply
        if hired:
            self.give_post(employee, role)

    def hire_employee(self, employee, role):
        if self.employee_eligible(employee, role):
            key = len(self.employee_dict)
            value = employee.__dict__
            self.employee_dict[key] = value
            # returns index of employee in list, used later
            print("You got the job")
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def give_post(self, employee, role):
        employee.employee_num = len(self.employee_dict) - 1
        employee.has_job = True
        employee.role = role
        employee.available_leaves = self.employee_max_leaves
        employee.salary_dollars = employee.grades_percent_average * 1000
        employee.company = self

class LeaveValidator:

    def employee_ask_leaves(self, employee, leaves_required):
        ask_leaves = self.give_leaves(employee, leaves_required)
        if ask_leaves:
            employee.working_days -= leaves_required

    def give_leaves(self, employee, leaves_required):
        if leaves_required <= 3 and employee.available_leaves - leaves_required >= 0:
            employee.available_leaves -=  leaves_required
            print("Leaves are granted.")
            return True
        else:
            print("Leaves can't be granted.")
            return False

class Company(Hirer, HiringRequirements, LeaveValidator):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.minimum_hiring_grades_percent = 90
        self.employee_max_leaves = 30
        self.name = name
        self.employee_dict = {}

    def promote_employee(self, employee, salary_increase):
        employee.salary_dollars += salary_increase
        if not "Head" in employee.role:
            employee.role = f"Head {employee.role}" 
            print(f"{employee.name} is promoted to {employee.role}")

    def print_company_employees(self):
        self.employees = [
            v
            for (key, value) in self.employee_dict.items()
            for (k, v) in value.items()
            if k == "name" 
        ]
        print(self.employees)

    def employee_fire(self, employee):
        self.employee_dict.pop(employee.employee_num)
        self.employee_del_attr(employee)
        print(f"{employee.name} is fired from {self.name}")

    def employee_resignation(self, employee):
        self.employee_dict.pop(employee.employee_num)
        self.employee_del_attr(employee)

    def employee_del_attr(self, employee):
        del employee.company
        del employee.salary_dollars
        del employee.employee_num
        employee.has_job = False

class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, number, grades):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.working_days = 300
        self.bonus_percent = 30
        self.has_job = False
        self.grades_percent_average = grades
        self.employee_num = None
```

I believe my code isn't the most design friendly so,
I would like to receive feedback on:

1. If `HiringRequirements` and `Hirer` should be merged.
2. If methods such as `employee_resignation` and `employee_fire` should have their own
   class for example: `RemoveEmployee`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class Company(Hirer, HiringRequirements, LeaveValidator):`
is an interesting implementation of c# `partial` through python's multiple inheritance, although it comes with some serious problems. To be honest, this is the first time I see it used like that, thumbs up for ingenuity (but don't do that ever again).

By looking at `HiringRequirements` we can't tell what `self.minimum_hiring_grades_percent` and `self.employee_dict.items` are since they are not defined here.

These classes don't encapsulate any data and they can't be used in any way other than being a base class for `Company` which makes them just a bunch of related methods grouped under a header.

Instead you can turn them into real classes:

```
class HrDepartment:

    def __init__(self):
        self.employee_dict = {}
        self.min_hiring_grades = DEFAULT_MIN_HIRING_GRADES
        self.employee_max_leaves = DEFAULT_EMPLOYEE_MAX_LEAVES

    def employee_application(self, employee, role):
        ...

    def hire_employee(self, employee, role):
        ...

    def give_post(self, employee, role):
        ...

    def employee_eligible(self, employee, role):
        ...

    def role_occupied(self, role):
        ...
```

Now we have our own data to work with! And it's fully defined in the constructor.
Now instead of inheritance () use composition ():

```
class Company():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hr_department = HrDepartment()

    def employee_fire(self, employee):
        self.hr_department.employee_dict.pop(employee.employee_num)
        self.employee_del_attr(employee)
        print(f"{employee.name} is fired from {self.name}")
```

---

`Company.employees` and `Employee.salary_dollars` are not defined in the constructor block which makes in unclear what fields our classes actually have. Read more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38378757/16763958).

---

Storing employees in a `dict` is weird, especially since the keys are... just their serial numbers? You could use `list` for that. Also for practice I would recommend making a tree for that purpose where each `Manager(Employee)` stores a list of their direct subordinates. A simple list is fine though if you don't want hierarchy.

---

Method names should reflect what they do and what to expect in return. You follow this rule mostly but there are some places for improvement:
`is_role_occupied` instead of `role_occupied`
`is_employee_eligible` instead of `employee_eligible`
`employee_application` should be a part of `hire_employee`
`ask_for_leave` (instead of `employee_asks_leaves`) should be an instance method of `Employee`
`resign` (instead of `employee_resignation`) should be an instance method of `Employee`

---

To sum it up: when you write a class make sure it encapsulates data and (optionally) does something with that data (instance methods). Writing a company model like this is a great way to practice OOP. Good luck!

Comment: I don't know "C#s partial", but that design pattern is called [mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin).

Comment: @ades it says in the definition: "without having to be the parent class of those other classes". Although they provide a python example where it is in fact one of the parent classes. However it's used in a different way from the code in question: there it acts as a way to create subclasses without any code duplication, which is [brilliant](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/socketserver.py#L716).

Comment: I would like to point out a funny thing, I initally had ```ask_for_leave``` in ```Employee``` which actually sent a request to the ```ask_for_leave``` I had in another class ```HiringApplication```, which was a mess. I guess I could have removed the intermediatery ```ask_for_leave``` in ```HiringApplication```. I later split up ```HiringApplication``` into the 2 classes you see. I used a dict as initially ```emloyee_num``` was a list index, and when an employee resigns, the ```employee_num``` of all other employees is invalidated

Comment: @QuasiStellar I noticed some of the functions such as ```employee_fire``` are in ```Company``` and other are in ```HrDepartment```. Is there any reason for this. Also, what is ```DEFAULT_MIN_HIRING_GRADES```?

Comment: @Illusioner_ `fire_employee` does indeed belong to the `HrDepartment`, I used it in the second code snipped (without thinking about it) to illustrate composition. `DEFAULT_MIN_HIRING_GRADES` is a constant. I forgot to mention it but you should avoid [plain numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) in the code since it's often unclear for the reader where they came from. Those constants can be declared at the top of the file.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this really changed my perspective about OOP. I saw a video doing something similar to your answer, but didn't think much of it, and thought it was inefficient.